# How do I create a new language pack for Knative Functions?

Tags: knative, knative-functions

I'd like to be able to write Knative functions in `bash`.  I'm thinking something like the CGI interface that Apache uses might make sense -- just write a script that can be executed in a "normal" Unix environment, and then use Apache's CGI support to turn it into a container that can run on Knative.

Is there a good way to do this?

I found https://knative.dev/docs/functions/language-packs/, but it wasn't really clear how to build my own language pack.